# Disable some php function on special directory

Tags: php, windows, apache

I want disable execute some php function like `file_put_content`,`exec`,`eval` on special directory.

I can use `disable_functions` in php.ini but how can define a special folder like `c:\poject\public`

Comment: set the appropriate permission like 644

Comment: do you want to disable all php functions or specific functions only

Answer (score 5):

If you have a working version of php.ini that disables the functions you want, then you just need to "link" the folder to that specidif .ini file. This means that your web server should, when serving files from that directory, should use that specific .ini file instead of the system one.

If you are using Apache2 as a server, a solution can be found [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php) you can define a specific php.ini file for each virtualhost. Let's say you specific folder is /var/www/web1, you should put the php.ini with the function disabled into /var/www/web1 and use this Apache2 configuration

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
[...]
PHPINIDir /var/www/web1
[...]
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are not familiar with or not using VirtualHosts (but still using Apache2), another possibile solution is putting PHP configuration into a file named .htaccess in the folder, with a syntax like this:

```
php_value disable_functions "file_put_content,exec,eval"
```

Comment: Have you actually tried either of these? I'm pretty sure you can only have one PHPINI directive that loads php globally. Furthermore, disable_functions is a system setting that you can't override in .htacess. So I don't think either will work. One way is to have virtual servers running different installations/versions of php. That's more complex that you are suggesting, but should work. But still not on a per-directory basis. But happy to be stand corrected if you've tried it.

Comment: Actually the 2nd one will work, but it'll have to be in the vhost configuration

Comment: I tried the second one and DID NOT work. Nor the first.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the disable_functions setting anywhere other than in a php.ini file, according to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions),.

If you need per-vhost or **per-directory** restrictions on functions, I would suggest using separate instances of [PHP-FPM](https://php-fpm.org/), each of which can have its own php.ini. It also provides additional security benefits, such as complete sandboxing per daemon instance.

**EDIT:**

You can read about it on [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php)

**or**

[php-fpm example configuration](https://github.com/perusio/php-fpm-example-config) for both UNIX and TCP sockets.